# reload image/page after computation is complete from the server side

Tags: python, apache, http, flask

I have a python code that performs some fairly intense computations, and then generates a plot (png file) for display on the web. I'm using python, flask, mod_wsgi, and apache. Since the computation takes several seconds (around 10 seconds), I'd like to display a "LOADING" type image while the computation is happening so that the viewer doesn't think the server is messed up, and then the actual image when computations are complete. How can I do this from the server side (not using javascript in the web browser)? In the past I remember seeing a lot of web pages where it seemed like the server was pushing a new page to the browser (from what a recall most it was search engines on message forums). The answer to this question I believe is really an http related question, so it doesn't necessarily have to be specific to serving an image (it could be an html page), or using python, flask, mod_wsgi, or apache, but it would be great if an example could be giving for just that configuration.

Comment: Why don't you want to use JavaScript? I would just run the plotting in a separate thread and just poll it with JavaScript to see when it's done.

Comment: i guess part of the reason is that i don't know how to do that. would that mean the separate thread would have to save the computed data to the disk in some way? any links on doing separate threads and polling for completion of the thread?

Comment: Here is an example of a site that does what I am talking about. First a page comes up that says loading, Then the real page comes up in a few seconds. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=anything If you view the page source, it looks almost like two HTML pages are sent, but for some reason the browser just ignores the first one after the second one is sent. Is there a name for what they are doing here, and will it work with every browser? Will it work with other content types other than text/html?

Comment: Bugzilla uses [HTTP server push](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push) (specifically the method in the third paragraph). It doesn't seem to work in Chrome, and definitely doesn't work in IE.

Comment: okay. it's a little misleading though whether once again, IE is not supporting a standard, or if Bugzilla happens to be not in compliance with standards? i've seen a number of web pages in the past that had similar functionality and would be surprised if all of them were doing a non-standard thing. so no web cams that serve jpeg images that automatically refresh will work with IE then? i've seen many of these in the past and never noticed anyone say they don't work with IE.

Answer (score 0):

Before Javascript I did implement this by generating a page that had a refresh in the HTML header, with a delay of 2-3 seconds.

This page would redisplay itself until the code generating that page noticed that the 'result' was finished then generating different HTML code (without the refresh).

```
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
</HEAD>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware that this question is a bit old now, but I feel like there is not enough information available on this topic. I was struggling with this myself to find a relevant information, so I hope this will help:

**Suggested solution**

There are different technologies that can be used here, but I believe the simplest would be [Server Sent Events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events). The implementation for Flask [can be found here](https://github.com/DazWorrall/flask-sse). The last part of the documentation is really important:

> Subscribers will connect and block for a long time, so you should seriously consider running under an asynchronous WSGI server, such as gunicorn+gevent

So make sure fulfil the requirement. Also, it's pretty important to understand that this approach is good if you want to send the messages from *your* server to the client. In case you have an external worker that does the calculations for you this method will only make it more complicated for you, since your server will have to play the role of a middle man between the browser and the worker machine. On some hostings it may even not work as expected (e.g. Heroku - still not sure why it misbehaves, looks like too many updates from the worker and are not propagated properly to the client). In case you use the same host for your app and the workers, you should have no problem though.

**Alternate solution**

In my opinion this type of calculations belong to background, so this solution assumes that we have some kind of workers doing the job for you (like I had when I first encountered the problem). Note that this solution is not a server->client communication, but it's based on polling. I think this may be the only option if you don't run on the asynchronous server in production.

So let's assume you have a worker which status you can check, for example Iron Worker. The user visits your page and this invokes the calculations on the worker. From this point on you should use AJAX calls to get the status update directly from your worker. What I did in my app, I used jQuery to poll the worker web api and learn about it's status. After you discover that your worker is done, you can just reload the page or just the image or whatever else you need.

**Additional information**

If you need to update many places at the same time (not only the browser), you can use queue services, for example ironMQ, which allows you to propagate your messages to a special queue, and then subscribe to this queue with a client and receive the messages from it. This is what I did before I discovered I can query the worker directly for it's status.